Can't accept suggestions in Github Copilot
I installed Github Copilot and suggestions do appear, but I am unable to accept them.
When I press Tab, the suggestion disappears and I can see in the output window a log message

[INFO] [CopilotProposalSourceProvider] Completion dismissed

I do have R#, but I have it set to use Visual Studio Intellisense now, although that didn't fix anything anyway.
I can't find anything in Keyboard commands windows to accept suggestion to check the keybinds for.

I'm not sure why or how, but right-arrow key is working for accepting the suggestion.
